# Jar file can't access Mysql database when moved to another computer

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jar

What the title says, basically. I have created a program for managing a database, and it worked perfectly inside and outside of the Netbeans IDE. However, as soon as I move it to another computer it can't access the database anymore. I don't know what the problem is, both computers are on the same LAN so they should be able to access the same localhost.

Comment: What is the URL of the database?

Comment: "the same localhost" <- localhost is usually the alias used to refer to ones own machine. So 2 systems will not have have access to the same localhost as in each system localhost will refer to itself. Maybe you just worded that wrong and actually mean a machine in the local network when you said localhost, but i feel this is worth pointing out

Comment: It's probably the classpath that's wrong now. Please [post](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors) errors when run from the command line. The driver will have to be in the classpath

Comment: @SimonMartinelli the url I used is jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS oh, so the problem could be my use of localhost in the url? what should i replace it with then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url is:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase
```

localhost is only valid on your local computer. If you want to access a database on another computer you have to use the hostname or the IP address of this computer.

For example:

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.110:3306/javabase
```